# How can this work?

Tags: php, html

I know this code doesn't work. I want to pass $var1, $var2, and name to next.php. How can I do that?

```
<?php
    $var1="test1";
    $var2="test2";
?>

<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <a <?php echo "href='next.php?test1=".$var1."&test2=".$var2."'"?> >next</a>
</form>
```

in next.php

```
$var1=$_GET['name'];
$var2=$_GET['test1'];
$var3=$_GET['test2'];
```

Comment: Whats the point of the form when you've assigned the variables with something already?

Comment: In what way does this "not work"?  What is the resulting HTML that this generates?  What happens when you click on that link?  What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: That is not how you create a form submission.

Comment: the title really needs work

Comment: pretty sure a simple tutorial on PHP and forms would have shown the correct way to do this.

Comment: and href does not belong in form.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the values as hidden inputs so that your other values in the form would still be passed with it.

```
<form action="next.php">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="hidden" name="test1" value="<?php echo $var1; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="test2" value="<?php echo $var2; ?>">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then in your `next.php`, you will receive everything in the `$_GET`.

Example, if the user fills in `Foo` as the name and click on submit, then you will receive the following in your `next.php`:

### var_dump($_GET)

```
array(3) {
    ["name"]=> string(3) "Foo"
    ["test1"]=> string(5) "test1"
    ["test2"]=> string(5) "test2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to :

```
<form method='GET' action='next.php'>
   <input type='text' name='name' />
   <input type='hidden' name='test1' value="<?php echo $var1;?>" />
   <input type='hidden' name='test2' value="<?php echo $var2;?>" />
</form>
```